# Vref out and OCXO

Tags: oscillator

[image]

Taken an OCXO and assuming that Vref in should stand for EFC (Electronic Frequency Control)  accepting an external reference voltage what is the general purpose of Vref Out in oscillators? And, in case of external Vref in, should the Vref Out be still connected as in the diagram?

Comment: What's the part number and datasheet?

Comment: I am not referring specifically to this oscillator btw, but to any OXCO with VREF IN/OUT

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a part number and datasheet are required to answer the question.

Comment: https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/100331/VECTRON/C4550.html

Answer (score 1):

Your "symbol" is indeed correct.

A VCOCXO is trimmed by applying an adjustment voltage, to the "Vref In" or "Vadj" pin.  (This signal needs to be stable and low noise, if you are to avoid undesirable modulation on the output.)  Internally it is then compared to a fixed reference voltage, to give a % correction signal.

The correction signal can be generated from an external DAC/control circuit, but the simplest case is a simple trim pot.  You ground one end of the track, attach the other end to a stable, low noise voltage source (maximum matching the internal Vref), and the wiper is connected to the "Vadj" pin.

To allow this case without additional complexity, many/most VXOCXO will provide a "Vref Out" for this precise purpose, which is simply a buffered version of the internal reference voltage (hence **"Vref Out"**).

Looking at the quoted Vectron datasheet, you can in fact see the level of this signal matches the upper limit of the adjustment voltage that can be applied to "Vref In".